# All accordions collapsed at the same time when I click on any one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

I am creating accordions with reactstrap but when I wanna open one accordion all accordions collapsed
I wanna every accordion work separately

my code that I created 2 components in it

```
const SellerShipping = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(null);
  const [toggleChecked, setToggleChecked] = useState(false)
  return (
    <Wrapper>
        <TagLine>Shipping and delivery</TagLine>
        <SearchBar>
        <SearchBox />
        <SuggestButton>suggest a company</SuggestButton>
        </SearchBar>
        <AccordionWrapper className=''>
            <CompanyAccordion toggleChecked={toggleChecked} setToggleChecked={setToggleChecked} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} toggleid={"1"} />
            <CompanyAccordion toggleChecked={toggleChecked} setToggleChecked={setToggleChecked} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} toggleid={"2"} />
        </AccordionWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

and even if I write states inside the accordion file its the same result
the company accordion

```
import { Accordion, AccordionBody, AccordionHeader, AccordionItem } from 'reactstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ReactSwitch from 'react-switch';
import { ReactComponent as EmiratesPost } from 'assets/img/logos/emirates-post.svg'


const CompanyAccordion = ({open, setOpen, toggleid, toggleChecked, setToggleChecked}) => {
  const toggle = (id) => {
    open === id ? setOpen() : setOpen(id);
    console.log(id,open);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <SubWrapper>
      <EmiratesPost style={{maxWidth:"100%"}} />
      <SwitchComponent>
      <ReactSwitch onChange={()=>setToggleChecked(!toggleChecked)} checked={toggleChecked}/>
      </SwitchComponent>
      </SubWrapper>
      <AccordionWrapper>
      <Accordion  open={open} toggle={toggle}>
        <AccordionItem style={{border:"0px"}} >
          <AccordionHeader targetId={toggleid}>
            Accordion Item 1
          </AccordionHeader>
          <AccordionBody accordionId={toggleid}>
            <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong>
            You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
          </AccordionBody>
        </AccordionItem > 
      </Accordion>
      </AccordionWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
  
}
```

the result
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zxFq.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have used the same state `toggleChecked` for all Accordions so they are behaving identically use different states of all the Accordions you wish to have separate behaviour

Comment: it the same even after I used another `toggleChecked`  and `open` states

Comment: ok 
So in your code i noticed `<Accordion  open={open} toggle={toggle}>` you haven't passed `id`?